# Getting all site collections with csom does not work when created with new office admin portal

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, csom

I can retrive all site collection information with the following code:

```
Tenant tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
props = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);
ctx.Load(props);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (SiteProperties sp in props) {...}
```

But when I create a new site collection with the new Office 365 admin portal, the created site collections are not listed in props. I can only see the one created with the old admin portal.

Did I miss sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePoint method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt779503%28v%3Doffice.15%29) to achieve it. The Tenant.GetSiteProperties method won't return the Site Collections created on new modern site templates.

```
Tenant tenant = new Tenant(context);
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable siteProps = tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePoint("0", true);
context.Load(siteProps);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Total Site Collections: " + siteProps.Count.ToString());
foreach (var site in siteProps)
{
    Console.WriteLine(site.Title +"\t"+ site.Template.ToString());
}
```

Reference: [Get All Site Collections from SharePoint Online Tenant](http://www.ktskumar.com/2018/05/get-site-collections-sharepoint-online-tenant/)

Comment: If it works, please mark the reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum.